# Kouchnirenko's theorem for non-generic polynomials

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, toric-varieties, tropical-geometry

In [Polyèdres de Newton et nombres de Milnor](https://eudml.org/doc/142365) (Theorem 1.18), Kouchnirenko proved that given Laurent polynomials $f_1, \dotsc, f_k$ in $k$ variables, the number of isolated solutions is less than or equal to the volume of the Minkowski sum of their Newton polyhedra (multiplied by $k!$). He also showed that equality holds whenever such polynomials are *generic*. In particular, in the generic case, if there is no solution, then the volume is 0. The question is whether this last statement is also true without the genericity assumption. (I am especially interested in the case $k = 2$.)

Comment: The equations $x+y=1$ and $x+y=2$ have no common solution, but the mixed volume is $1$. Does that mean that the answer is "no", or did I misunderstand your question?

Comment: I guess this does answer the question... thanks! Perhaps I can do an update with a second question, namely, if there is any lower bound for the number of solutions in terms of the mixed volume, or if there is any correction term to get equality in the non-generic case. Anything known in this direction?

Comment: Dear David, do you know by any chance if there is any known result when the 2 polynomials are $f(x,y)$ and $y (\partial f/\partial y)$?

Comment: In this particular case, you could possibly make some progress using the Riemann-Hurwitz formula. $f(x,y)=0$ is a curve $C$ with some genus, and the solutions to $f=\partial f/\partial y=0$ are the ramification points of the projection of $C$ onto the $x$-axis.

Comment: Many thanks for the answer!